# JAVASCRIPT - Resizing child window when it opens as full screen tab.

Tags: javascript

I have tried this two ways, neither works or shows me console errors so I am bit stumped.

```
function resizeMe() {
  let myWindow;
myWindow.resizeTo("width=200","height=200");
}
```

and

```
function resizeMe() {
window.resizeTo("width=200","height=200");
}
```

The page I am attempting to resize is loaded by this default behavior method.

```
function start() {
   window.open("example1.html");
}
```

I know I can open the new browser window with specific sizing however, I wanted to specially change the size of the new window once it is opened full screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems that needs to be fixed,

When you initialize `let myWindow` inside of resize there is no way for your browser to know which `window` exactly.

To fix that we can use a global variable,

```
var myWindow;
```

Now, the `.resizeTo` function takes two integer values, not a string with width and height values inside of it,

```
myWindow.resizeTo(250,250) // This is the right format
```

Windows opened in a tab can not be resized using `.resizeTo`, you have to open that window by passing the spec of the window which can contain its initial width and height like this

```
window.open("http://example.com", "", "width=100, height=100")
```

Putting this all together, we can create what you are looking to get:

```
var myWindow;
function start(){
    myWindow = window.open( "http://example.com", "", "width=500, height=500" );
   // If you want the window to span across the screen, use JavaScript to fill the values for height and width in the third parameter that's been passed to window.open
}

function resizeMe() {
    myWindow.resizeTo( 200, 200 );
}
```